# Update multiple embeded documents in array based on their property values

Tags: mongodb

I have a demo collection. In every document of the collection there is a array which contains several documents.A sample document is:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  persons: [{
    name: "Jack",
    gender: "Male"
  }, {
    name: "Ma",
    gender: "Female"
  }, {
    name: "Ho",
    gender: "Other"
  }]
}
```

Think I want to change only the `name` property of `gender= Male` and `gender= Other` of  **nested documents** in `persons` array of document `_id = 1` and based on the `gender`'s value the `name` property  of each document value will be different.

Think `gender= Male`'s document's `name`'s value will be "Jul" and `gender= Other`'s document's `name`'s value will be "Tisa"

How can I design my single update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [arrayfilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        _id: 1,
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "persons.$[elem].name": "new_name",
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{"elem.gender": {$in: ["Male", "Other"]}}]
    });
```

---

EDIT:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        _id: 1,
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "persons.$[elem].name": "Jul",
            "persons.$[elem2].name": "Tisa",
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {"elem.gender": "Male"},
            {"elem2.gender": "Other"},
        ]
    });
```

Comment: i edited my answer, just change the conditions for the arrayFilters.